# How to make a customize UITableView with dynamic cell height?

Tags: ios, uitableview, height

### This question is not regarding creating dynamic cell height based on text

[image]

As in the screenshot attached, I'll need to show 4 different options in `UITableView`, the first three rows having different options, then a big heighted row will be a free space, and at last row there'll be some option.

I know I'll need to add extra cells with that much of height but know it'll be hacky!

Other solution, I can add footer view too, but it'll add very next to 3rd row that I don't want, I want this much of space as in screenshot,

#### what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is this going to be a static table view? Does the last item need to be a cell?

Comment: you can set height by using delegate method.

Comment: No its dynamic table, based on user logged-in status, the current screenshot attached is without logged-in, if user will logged-in, there'll be more options added, but the flow and look will be same. About last item, if I can make it cell then it'll be good when user tap on table. @Wain

Comment: Yes, I know I can set height based on conditions but I don't want to make my code tricky! **Until it wont be a last need!** @Sunny

Comment: Based on text you need to set Height of the cell?

Comment: @Sunny, NO! Please have a look on question again!

Comment: On what constraints your cell should be framed if you could give some insight..

Answer (score 0):

Create it with a table and a number of custom cells. Consider maybe a state type pattern such that your controller manages the top level status (logged in) and decides which state should manage the table view delegate / data source callbacks.

This is really a problem about how you organise your code rather than anything else. There isn't necessarily a single best solution.

Get it working first, then you can look at refactoring later.

You can also think about having custom cells that display differently based on a flag you send them (like hiding some / all of their subviews).